# Java Generics with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

There is any way to fix this situation (I have try to simplyfy the scenario as much as i could):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * HERE I would like to indicate that the CollectionGeneric can be of
         * something that extends Animal (but the constructor doesn't allow
         * wildcards)
         */
        CollectionGeneric<? extends Animal> animalsCollectionGeneric = new CollectionGeneric<Animal>();
        List<? extends Animal> animals = getAnimals();
        /* Why I cannt do that? */
        animalsCollectionGeneric.setBeans(animals);
    }

    private static List<? extends Animal> getAnimals() {
        return new ArrayList<Dog>();
    }
}

class CollectionGeneric<T> {
    private List<T> beans;

    public List<T> getBeans() {
        return (beans != null) ? beans : new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public void setBeans(List<T> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }
}

interface Animal {}

class Dog implements Animal{}
```

this scenario is giving me the next error:

```
The method setBeans(List<capture#2-of ? extends Animal>) in the type    
CollectionGeneric<capture#2-of ? extends Animal> is not applicable for
the arguments (List<capture#3-of ? extends Animal>)*
```

I am not sure about if there is a way to do this with generics,

Comment: Out of interest, why would you use CollectionGeneric and not just use the List?

Comment: @Nick Holt: As I said at the beginning this a really simplyfied version of my problem, trust me, I have to use that CollectionGeneric class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What this means is that the two collections can not be proved to have the same type bounds:

```
    CollectionGeneric<? extends Animal> animalsCollectionGeneric = 
             new CollectionGeneric<Animal>(); 
    List<? extends Animal> animals = getAnimals()
```

The first one might at runtime have `CollectionGeneric<Tiger>` and the second one `List<Gnu>`. Mixing those would mean you lose the type safety ( not to mention the carnage ).

Therefore you need to prove to the compiler that those two are related, so your generic signatures should be:

```
public void setBeans(List<? extends T> beans) {}
public List<T> getBeans();
```

and used as:

```
List<? extends Animal> beans = getBeans();
GenericCollection<Animal> animals = new GenericCollection<Animal>();
animals.add(beans);
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that if you wanted to add an addBeans() method, it could simply take an object of type T. Josh Bloch gave a talk that went into generics and wildcards at Google I/O. See http://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded